# Getting "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression" in a PHP app

Tags: php, sql, oracle, ora-00979

I test with mysql it work, but when I used Oracle, this error appear:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
$sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM policy order by policyprogress_id asc";
if (isset($_GET['batch']) && !empty($_GET['batch'])) {
  $batch = $_GET['batch'];
  $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM policy where batch = '".$batch."' group by type order by policyprogress_id asc";
  if (isset($_GET['type']) && !empty($_GET['type'])) {
    $type = $_GET['type'];
    $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM policy where batch = '".$batch."' and type = '".$type."' order by policyprogress_id asc";
  }
}
```

Comment: **Warning**: your code has serious SQL injection vulnerabilities. Please research this and fix it before going live with this code - currently this code is not safe to run, and could get your website hacked. That means people accessing systems they should not, or people stealing data that you have a responsibility to protect, or destroying data that will stop your system working.

Comment: @beginner . . . .Oracle is correct.  `SELECT *` is broken with `GROUP BY`.  If you want an idea of how to fix this problem, then ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.  I doubt you need three queries for this.  One would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You have a total of 3 queries

```
-- 1
SELECT * FROM policy order by policyprogress_id asc ;

-- 2
SELECT * FROM policy where batch = '".$batch."' 
group by type order by policyprogress_id asc;

 -- 3
SELECT * FROM policy where batch = '".$batch."' and type = '".$type."' 
order by policyprogress_id asc;
```

Your second query will throw an error as You are doing `SELECT *` but also using `GROUP BY TYPE`.

In `GROUP BY` queries, `SELECT` clause can only include the grouped columns and aggregate functions. If you try to use other than grouped columns in the `SELECT` clause then Oracle will throw `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` error.

Comment: thank you for replying. i have improve the query. but the same error still appear.

Comment: How exactly did you improve it, @beginner?

Comment: i try improving the query by following the answer above at second query

Comment: share the actual query that you are trying as an improvement

Comment: $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM policy group by batch order by policyprogress_id asc";

  $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM policy where batch = '".$batch."' group by type order by policyprogress_id asc";
 
    $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM policy where batch = '".$batch."' and type = '".$type."' order by policyprogress_id asc";

Comment: Nope. What is an enhancement in the second query? It is still the same. remove `*` from `SELECT` and take the `TYPE` and necessary aggregate functions in the `SELECT`. By the way what doo you expect from second query?

Comment: Tejash: please **always** mention SQL injection vulnerabilities when you see them. Ideally any code you provide should use parameter binding, but if you don't want to go to that trouble, at least put a prominent note in your answers.